# Facebook offline access. Updating status via cron job?

Tags: php, facebook

My users have allowed offline access. I have the infinite access token, but can't figure out how to update the status from a cron job.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 quite interesting question. Did you able to get it done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store their sessions somewhere, then use the `setSession` method of the Facebook SDK to populate it prior to making the request as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Johannes, thanks for the tip about `setSession`. It worked, i do it like that now:

```
    $api = new FB();
    $api->setSession( unserialize($u['User']['stored_session'] ));
```

one question that remains, is for how long this session is valid.